# Replicate Metadata gives system configured incorrectly Error in SAP BI 7.0

Tags: business-intelligence, sap-erp, sap-bw

I am using a brand new IDES system to test create a generic extractor from ECC6.0 (EHP4 FOR SAP ERP 6.0 / NW7.01) , but my BW and R/3 system is **in the same instance**. I have configured this option:

1. the global setting "BW User ALE" - BWREMOTE
2. the profiles: S_BI-WX_RFC and S_BI-WHM_RFC
3. I have activated my datasource
4. the connection test is OK
5. RSA3 test is OK.

but when I used "**replicate metadata** " in RSA1 , intending to activate my datasource, but I got this error when the progress is in about 80% :

> The system is configured incorrectly
>
> Message no.RSAR051

I have searched on the internet and notes, but in vain. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

My error occurred while I was activating the datasource , so I *deleted most of the datasource* . By re-activating ***SAP-R/3*** and ***NODESNOTCONNECTED*** datasource, although some error/warning occurred in the process of activating, I *replicate the metadata* again, no error occurred, finally I solved my problem.